# Как подключить в JFrame вот этот код? В консоль выводится всё верно, а при подключении JFrame-выдает ошибку

Tags: java

Создал в JFrame два поля, также есть одна кнопка. При вызове метода, текст из поле 1 должен попасть в поле 2 с измененными символами. Программа запускается, но при вводе одного символа в поле 1- программа крашится. Не могу понять, почему выдает компилятор ошибку. И складывается параллельный вопрос- при вызове метода Scanner у меня всегда запускается командная строка и JFrame окно, и среда ставит приоритет на ввод информации из командной строки. Какие методы использовать, чтобы всё происходило только в всплывающем окне?

Кусочек кода:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
String pole_dlya_texta_1 = null;
String pole_dlya_texta_2 = null;
pole_dlya_texta_2 = scanner.nextLine();   
pole_dlya_texta_2 = pole_dlya_texta_2.replace("е", "s"); 
pole_dlya_texta_2 = pole_dlya_texta_2.replace("д", "k");
pole_dlya_texta_2.setText(pole_dlya_texta_1.getText());
}
```

Comment: Не получится использовать `System.in` и `JFrame`, для ввода текста с  `JFrame` есть `JTextField` и `JTextArea`

Comment: @Denis Rudnitskiy У вас ссылка pole_dlya_texta_2 не инициализирована. Поэтому это предложение pole_dlya_texta_2 = pole_dlya_texta_2.replace("е", "s"); не корректное

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Инициализировал, все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: @Stranger in the Q В том то и дело, что я и использую JTextArea

Comment: Вы ожидаете что будете печатать в `JTextArea` и получите ввод через `System.in` ?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, нет, в вопросе была задана параллельная проблема...какой метод нужно использовать, чтобы предотвратить ввод пользователем из командной строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По Вашему вопросу с `JTextArea`:

```
JTextArea pole_dlya_texta_1 = new JTextArea();
JTextArea pole_dlya_texta_2 = new JTextArea();
...
String s = pole_dlya_texta_1.getText();   
s = s.replaceAll("е", "s"); 
s = s.replaceAll("д", "k");
...
pole_dlya_texta_2.setText(s);
```

Для замены всех символов в строке используйте [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

А `System.in` просто не используйте